# How to properly center website for Safari screenshot

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a simple one page website which is meant to be entered across the page.

This is the basic structure of the page:

```
<html><head>
        <style>
            body {
                position: absolute;
                top: 25%;
                -moz-transform: translateY(-25%);
                -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
                transform:  translateY(-25%);
                background-color: #4e5a65;
                font-family:san fransisco, helvetica neue thin, helvetica neue, helvetica, arial;
                font-size: 24px;
                color: #E4F1FE;
            }
            a {
                color: #abd4fc;
                font-family:san fransisco, helvetica neue thin, helvetica neue, helvetica, arial;

                text-decoration: none;
            }

            a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            a:active {
                color: white;
            }

            a:visited {
                color: #fdd1e7;
            }
            li {
                margin: 10px 0;
            }
          h5 {
            margin-top: 1px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
          }
          h1 {
            margin-bottom: 0px;
          }
        </style>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Title Text</h1>

</body></html>
```

I'd like the content to be centered horizontally, and to begin at the top of the page with some margin. When I navigate to the website this is the case. However Safari's screenshot utility produces this:

[image: Diagram illustrating issue]

Am I not using the industry-standard method to center my content? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the body styling with this:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #4e5a65;
  font-family: san fransisco, helvetica neue thin, helvetica neue, helvetica,
    arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #e4f1fe;
}
```

If you want only 25% from the top then just change the top value and not the transform value.

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/ZEpMExW

#### A much better approach to aligning horizontally will be to use:

```
margin 0 auto;
```

like this:

```
body {
  margin 0 auto;
  background-color: #4e5a65;
  font-family: san fransisco, helvetica neue thin, helvetica neue, helvetica,
    arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #e4f1fe;
}
```

here to give top margin just change margin's `0`. but don't change `auto`.

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/rNMZNKW